# Joomla Adding A Custom Form

Tags: php, forms, joomla

I am new to Joomla. I have the basic set up and also did some modifications to my registration form. I wanted to know, how can I add a new form from scratch in Joomla.

I tried using the chronoform extension, but couldnt figure out what action to put for the form. Can anyone tell me how the routing works in Joomla.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the form wizard in Chronoforms. You don't need to put anything in the action, it will do it for you. There is a tutorial for how to make a Chronoforms registration form here - http://www.chronoengine.com/component/rokdownloads/51-4-building-a-joomla-registration-form-using-chronoforms.html